# show element on textarea focus

Tags: javascript, focus, textarea

I have a textarea and I only want the submit button the appear when the texarea has been focused.

Could you give me a javascript code to make the button appear when the textarea has been focused?

Comment: Please post relevant code.  I'm sure it's something minor.

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of your issue.  We will show the submit once a given textarea has been focused:

```
 $('textarea').focus(function() {
   $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="submit"]').show();
 });
```

I have it all put together in a nice [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDdsu/).  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This is super easy with jQuery.

For this HTML

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<br />
<input id="submit" type="submit" />
```

Use this

```
$('#text').focus(function(){
    $('#submit').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/F65TX/

Note the `submit button` is set to `display:none;` in the CSS originally.

**EDIT**

Seeing you tagged this javascript, a plain way to add this would be through the `onfocus` event:

```
<textarea onfocus="document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';" id="text"></textarea>
<br />
<input id="submit" type="submit" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/F65TX/1/

Again, assuming the `submit button` is set to `display:none;` in the CSS originally.